# SQLite Flask - Can't open database file in EC2 when running db.create_all() command

Tags: amazon-web-services, sqlite, flask, amazon-ec2

I just deployed a flask app to EC2 AWS, and when trying to initialise a sqlite db by using the db.create_all(bind=['layout']) method, an error was shown

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) unable to open database file
```

Here is my code

```
application.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "postgresql://{}:{}@{}/{}".format(os.getenv('DB_USER'), os.getenv('DB_PASSWORD'), os.getenv('DB_SERVER'), os.getenv('DB_NAME'))
application.config['SQLALCHEMY_BINDS'] = {
    'dashboard': "postgresql://{}:{}@{}/{}".format(os.getenv('DB_USER'), os.getenv('DB_PASSWORD'), os.getenv('DB_SERVER'), os.getenv('DB_NAME')),
    'layout': "sqlite:///layout.db"
}
```

I ran db.create_all(bind=['layout']) in the python shell within the ec2 terminal, and I am not sure why I ran into the error, as it worked perfectly fine on my localhost.

The postgresql database works fine, and can be accessed properly, but the sqlite database, which is the one im trying to initialise with db.create_all(bind=['layout']) leads to the error shown above, and I am not sure why it isnt creating a 'layout.db' file within the current directory.

I am new to deployment, and am not sure if I did anything wrong, do let me know if I configured anything wrongly, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

"sqlite:///layout.db" may end up pointing to a place where your applications doesn't have permission to write. Instead try something like

```
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
...
layout': 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'layout.db')
```

Comment: thank you for responding, is it possible for me to use the 'sudo' command along with the running of the db.create_all() command somehow so that i can 'gain the permissions'?

Comment: You could, but it's risky